# Remove words from a String based on a list

Tags: google-sheets

Here's what I need to accomplish. I have a string with several words separated by a comma. Now, I need to remove any word from that string that is part of a list of words in another column.

You can see in the image that the String on Column D. On column E is my expected result, so basically, it removed any words listed in column B.

I've been trying to do that with regex, but I don't know how to tell regex to use a list of words.

Any ideas?

[image]

[Here's the link for the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u028Od3UYJx67083dkJVYLwzMiDWvjZXsHzSmg6OBxo/edit#gid=1227162412)

Comment: `I've been trying to do that with regex`. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="",,BYROW(REGEXREPLACE( D2:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,$B$2:$B), ""), 
                                LAMBDA(v, ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN( ", ", 1, TRIM(SPLIT(v, ","))))))))
```

[image]

**Resources**

[***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o8mVmS04JCkTVefTDcp2P-y1r4gmA8oMMfSrlZhJh4s/copy) of this example sheet or create your own from the tables down below.

```
String
mole, dugong, porcupine
ocelot, parakeet, colt
chimpanzee, cougar, mole, parakeet, ocelot
skunk, snake, mole
squirrel, skunk
raccoon, donkey
parakeet, lemur, dugong, giraffe
squirrel, ocelot
polar bear, cougar, lemur, dugong
parakeet, musk-ox, mountain goat, highland cow
raccoon, polar bear, gnu
raccoon, lemur, porcupine, mountain goat
raccoon, giraffe, ocelot
cougar, snake, donkey, porcupine, gnu, chimpanzee
donkey, parakeet, gnu, squirrel, musk-ox, giraffe
porcupine, giraffe
chimpanzee, porcupine
raccoon, highland cow, ocelot, lemur, squirrel
snake, giraffe, chimpanzee, musk-ox, squirrel
porcupine, colt, ocelot, highland cow, skunk
```

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|  Words I want | Words I dont want |
+---------------+-------------------+
| lemur         | cougar            |
+---------------+-------------------+
| colt          | highland cow      |
+---------------+-------------------+
| mountain goat | donkey            |
+---------------+-------------------+
| gnu           | snake             |
+---------------+-------------------+
| chimpanzee    | raccoon           |
+---------------+-------------------+
| squirrel      |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| skunk         |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| mole          |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| polar bear    |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| giraffe       |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| musk-ox       |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| dugong        |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| ocelot        |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| porcupine     |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
| parakeet      |                   |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer can be greatly improved if you add data as table. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than images to show your data structure as it's copyable.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the suggestion i will try it in the future

Comment: @TheMaster i will refine the answer this is a 3 min response

Comment: @BebetoLeGarfs The answer is updated, take a look

Comment: So I went with `=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="",, regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE( C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,$B$2:$B), ""), ", ,", ",")), "^[^A-Za-z]+", ""),",*$",""))`.      this way it removed any leading or trailing commas without losing any other carachters

Comment: @BebetoLeGarfs Consider trying the updated answer.

Comment: I'm curious. What does the Lamda function do? I tried reading the manual, but I didn't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248264/discussion-between-bebeto-le-garfs-and-osm).

Comment: @BebetoLeGarfs Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73817724/19529694)