# How to solve "Function LAMBDA should be followed by a call containing the actual values"?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula

I didn't understand the LAMBDA function documentation example in Google help. Can you show me the simplest example for beginners?

### The problem

I used this formula

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUM(x+2+x+5))
```

I get this error:

> Function LAMBDA should be followed by a call containing the actual values.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: I do not recommend creating the branch, [google-sheets-lambda], we made many branches with [google-apps-script] and [google-sheets]. It quickly became a mess. We had long discussions and we eventually decided most tags should be deleted and did mass retagging of questions. It was brutal. See the links in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401152) and the related chats. Just think whether this tag is absolutely necessary and whether it cannot be represented with a couple of other tags like [formula] and [lambda]. Simple is always better.

Comment: But the tag wiki doesn't represent google sheets see [this](https://i.imgur.com/uKAUd7a.jpg)

Comment: @TheMaster oh yes it's a mess edit this question back

Comment: Osm Your picture literally says Google sheets at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) avoids repititions by putting a range in [Lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) call like this
`LAMBDA([name, …], formula_expression)(range)` and subtitite the range in the rest of the formula_expression with a name, in this case `x` or multiple names [name, ...].

Imagin having a range repeated 5 or more times, and that range is a long formula output.

### Using one name : *x*

The Old way

```
=SUM(B2+2+B2+5)
```

The new way using [lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUM(x+2+x+5))(B2)
```

[image]

### Using multiple names: *x,y*

The Old way

```
=SUM(B2+2+B2+5)-B3*B3
```

The new way using [lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)

```
=LAMBDA(x,y, SUM(x+2+x+5)-y*y)(B2,B3)
```

[image]

### Common errors

You may encounter this error.

> **Error**
> Function LAMBDA should be followed by a call containing the actual values.

you probably wrote it like this 
`LAMBDA([name, …], formula_expression)`

It should be like this
`=LAMBDA([name, …], formula_expression)(range1,...)`
`=LAMBDA(x,y,       SUM(x+2+x+5)-y*y  )(B2    ,B3 )`