# Passing QUERY() as a parameter to a Google Sheets LAMBDA function

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, split, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheets offers passing in parameters to lambdas as such:
`=LAMBDA(x, y, x + y)(100, 200)`

I was thinking of taking 2 columns from another Sheet, filter it with QUERY and then pass those 2 columns into the LAMBDA. Basically the 2 columns were a key and a CSV text that I wanted to split in one go.

1. `=lambda(a, b, split(b, ","))(query('Alias Key Raw'!A1:B, "select * where A starts with 'X'"))`

This gives the following `ERROR Wrong number of arguments to call following LAMBDA function. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments.`. Given that QUERY provides 2 columns of actual values, I thought this would be possible.

2. `=byrow(query('Alias Key Raw'!A1:B, "select * where A starts with 'X'"), lambda(row, split(row, ",")))`

This gives me only column A. No error otherwise. All of column B is ignored it appears

3. I've tried using `BYCOL`, `BYROW`, etc, and a lot of errors are `ERROR Wrong number of arguments to call following LAMBDA function. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments.`

## Data

Input into the lambda

| Key | Lineages |
| --- | --- |
| CU | B.1.1.529.5.1.26 |
| CV | B.1.1.529.2.75.3.1.1.3 |
| XA | B.1.1.7,B.1.177 |
| XB | B.1.634,B.1.631 |
| XC | AY.29,B.1.1.7 |
| XAZ | BA.2.5,BA.5,BA.2.5 |
| XBC | BA.2*,B.1.617.2*,BA.2*,B.1.617.2* |

### Expected

Output from the lambda

| Key | Lineages |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XA | B.1.1.7 | B.1.177 |  |  |
| XB | B.1.634 | B.1.631 |  |  |
| XC | AY.29 | B.1.1.7 |  |  |
| XAZ | BA.2.5 | BA.5 | BA.2.5 |  |
| XBC | BA.2* | B.1.617.2* | BA.2* | B.1.617.2* |

Note: There can be any number of lineages in the CSV cell

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817724/how-to-solve-function-lambda-should-be-followed-by-a-call-containing-the-actual) have the same error

Comment: While playing around, I noticed the parentheses mismatch when I was verifying the code works independently of each other. It still doesn't work as expected

Comment: Share data sample

Comment: added sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(a, {QUERY({a},"Select Col1"),SPLIT(QUERY({a},"Select Col2"),",")})
 (QUERY('Alias Key Raw'!A1:B, "select * where A starts with 'X'",1)))
```

[image]

Explanaition:

using an Array `{}` to return:
Col1: `{QUERY({a},"Select Col1"),...}`
Col2: `{...,SPLIT(QUERY({a},"Select Col2"),",")}`

Of the `Query` `QUERY('Alias Key Raw'!A1:B, "select * where A starts with 'X'",1)` found in the `Lambda` call named `a`

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: try arrayformula Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: The answer is updated take a look @ChristopherRucinski

Comment: This works great! I think it even answers the original question, too. Basically do individual QUERY's to pull out the data and format it as needed. This solves to parameter mismatch issues

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps worth pointing out that the expected data can be returned with a more compact formula that uses neither QUERY nor LAMBDA:

```
=filter({A1:A,split(B1:B,",")},regexmatch(A1:A,"^X"))
```

Comment: Arrays are amazing. Thanks for this answer! Definitely cleaner and shorter. I might replace it with this or something similar if my expanded needs work with it (LAMBDA and named functions might be more beneficial). I did want to focus on LAMBDA as it's new and there are a lot of design patterns to develop and eventually I might need to do something like this again where FILTER on an processed array isn't enough